# Null Pointer exception using Page object model with Cucumber

Tags: selenium

I have used Page Object Model design pattern along with Cucumber. So for this I have created two pages named as `abstractPage` and `loginPage` but on running the script i get null pointer exception even when i have already initialize the webelements using pagefactory , please have a look at below code:

**abstractPage:**

```
public class abstractPage {

    protected WebDriver driver;
    public static loginPage lpOBJ;

    public void openBrowsernURLhit() {
        driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, loginPage.class);
    }
}
```

**loginPage:**

```
public class loginPage extends abstractPage {

    @FindBy(name = "email")
    public WebElement username;

    @FindBy(name = "pass")
    public WebElement password;

    @FindBy(id = "u_0_2")
    public WebElement loginButon;

    public void loginIntoApp() {

        String url=driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("the url is::::::::::::::::"+url);
        username.sendKeys("testuser");
        password.sendKeys("123");
    }

    public void clicklogn() {
        loginButon.click();
    }
}
```

And then I have a class `stepDefination` from where I am calling the above methods of login class. Browser is opened fine and url is hit but when it goes inside l`oginintoapp()` method it throws exception on first line itself.

```
public class SmokeTest {

    @Given("^Open Firefox and start application$")
    public void Open_Firefox_and_start_application() throws Throwable {

        abstractPage obj = new abstractPage();
        obj.openBrowsernURLhit();
    }

    @When("^I enter valid \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_enter_valid_username_and_password(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {

        loginPage lpobj = new loginPage();
        lpobj.loginIntoApp();
    }

    @Then("^user should be able to login successfully$")
    public void user_should_be_able_to_login_successfully() throws Throwable {

        loginPage lpobj = new loginPage();
        lpobj.clicklogn();
    }
}
```

**I also have a TestRunner class where i have glued my stepDefination:**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features= "features", 
        glue= {"stepDefination"},
        plugin= {"html:target/cucumber-html-report"}
        )

public class TestRunner {

}
```

But on running the above script I always get NullPointerException in first line ofloginIntoApp() method.I have already used Pagefactory to initialize webelements but i guess "driver" variable is not getting initialized in Login class though i have inherited asbtract class where i m instantiating the driver due to which it is throwing null pointer.Please see what I am i doing wrong here.Error is as follows:

> 1 Scenarios ([31m1 failed[0m)
>       3 Steps ([31m1 failed[0m, [36m1 skipped[0m, [32m1 passed[0m)
>       0m18.149s

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pages.loginPage.loginIntoApp(loginPage.java:22)
    at stepDefination.SmokeTest.I_enter_valid_username_and_password(SmokeTest.java:33)
    at ?.When I enter valid "t1@gmail.com" and "pass"(MyApp.feature:5)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please add the following constructor. It may solve the issue.

```
public loginPage(){
  PageFactory.initElements(driver, loginPage.class);
}
```

you can put outside as well like,

```
 public void loginIntoApp() { 
      String url=abstractPage.driver.getCurrentUrl(); 
      System.out.println("the url is::::::::::::::::"+url); 
      loginPage lp=PageFactory.initElements(abstractPage.driver, loginPage.class); 
      lp.username.sendKeys("testuser");
      lp.password.sendKeys("123");
   }
```

other way is,

```
public class SmokeTest extends abstractPage {

    @Given("^Open Firefox and start application$")
    public void Open_Firefox_and_start_application() throws Throwable {
            openBrowsernURLhit();
    }

    @When("^I enter valid \"([^\"]*)\" and \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_enter_valid_username_and_password(String arg1, String arg2) throws Throwable {

        loginPage lpobj = PageFactory.initElements(driver, loginPage.class);
        lpobj.loginIntoApp();
    }

    @Then("^user should be able to login successfully$")
    public void user_should_be_able_to_login_successfully() throws Throwable {

        loginPage lpobj = PageFactory.initElements(driver, loginPage.class);
        lpobj.clicklogn();
    }
}
```

Comment: actually it is working if return my driver from abstractpage class and accept it in the smoke test class in openBrowsernURLhit method n then use this driver variable , otherwise it doesnt work , dont knw why even after extending the class it does get the initialized driver variable

Comment: public void loginIntoApp() {
  
  String url=abstractPage.driver.getCurrentUrl();
  System.out.println("the url is::::::::::::::::"+url);
  PageFactory.initElements(abstractPage.driver, loginPage.class);
  username.sendKeys("testuser");

Comment: it still throw null pointer exception on line username.sendkeys("testuser");

Comment: ok it is working when i m putting pagefactory code inside constrcutor but not workng when i m putting it inside loginIntoAppmethod() as pased above , any idea why it behaves like that?

Comment: you can put outside as well like, public void loginIntoApp() { String url=abstractPage.driver.getCurrentUrl(); System.out.println("the url is::::::::::::::::"+url); loginPage lp=PageFactory.initElements(abstractPage.driver, loginPage.class); lp.username.sendKeys("testuser");

Comment: yes but putting it inside is not working which is my question

Comment: the problem here is the page factory elements should be initialized using the initElements method and it will return the object of  the page.

Comment: Instead of extending the abstract page class in login page, you can extend it with smokeTest class. so that you can initialize the page factory. updated the answer please check

Comment: Like you have mentioned : loginPage lp=PageFactory.initElements(abstractPage.driver, loginPage.class); 
      lp.username.sendKeys("testuser"); it works like this but if I uselike this::  PageFactory.initElements(abstractPage.driver, loginPage.class); 
      username.sendKeys("testuser"); then it thrwos null pointer , any idea why it behaves like this?

Comment: because username field is not initialized.

Comment: doesn"t it get initialized just on using pagefactory above that line?

Comment: Best practice, need to be initialized in step definition class/test class not inside the page factory class method

Answer (score -1):

the simplest way to solve the problem is to make your driver object static.

```
 protected static WebDriver driver;
```

as you are using page factory, you also need to initiazlize the page object, otherwise all the the `WebElement` will be `null`

```
  public loginPage(){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }
```

or this, which I don't think is a good practice and people should avoid this.

public void loginIntoApp() {

```
String url=driver.getCurrentUrl();
System.out.println("the url is::::::::::::::::"+url);
PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
username.sendKeys("testuser");
password.sendKeys("123");
```

}

Comment: I did like this bt still getting same exception:

Comment: public void loginIntoApp() {
  
  
  String url=abstractPage.driver.getCurrentUrl();
  System.out.println("the url is::::::::::::::::"+url);
  PageFactory.initElements(abstractPage.driver, loginPage.class);
  username.sendKeys("testuser");
 
 }

Comment: ok it is working when i m putting pagefactory code inside constrcutor but not workng when i m putting it inside loginIntoAppmethod() as pasted above , any idea why it behaves like that?

Comment: if you will look closely I have provided constructor and not a method. what you have done is put code in method. simply copy paste the code in your loginPage class and everything will work. Also, please read java before jumping into automation.

Comment: i said it works when putting it inside constructor which is fine but my question is why doesnt it work when putting it inside method?constructor part i m aware of , i have used it before inside method and it worked.